# Nested resources segments misplacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, nested-resources

I'm trying to implement basic social network features to allow users to add, delete friends, accept and decline friedship requests.

my user resource looks like this:

```
resources :users
    resources :friends, :controller => :relations
end
```

which generates this route `user_friend DELETE /users/:user_id/friends/:id`

But the problem is when I access `/users/1`, the generated link to the `delete_user_friend_path` looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/users/5/friends/1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the user into the helper:

```
delete_user_friend_path(@user, @friend)
```

It seems that you were doing:

```
delete_user_friend_path(@friend)
```

Which will fill in the `:user_id` parameter, and assume you want the same `:id` parameter as the page you are currently on.